# Unable to use basic authentication while passing user and password in url

Tags: java, http, authentication, url

I have a soap end-point, user and password.
user = "Org API/uAPI529457959-e784379"
password = "t61/B=09{v"

HttpClient Imports

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams;
```

I used Basic authentication in Request Header

```
String userPassword = user + ":" + password;
setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes())));
```

It is working fine.

But when I tried to pass the user and password in end-pont url like.
http://user:password@example.com

It is giving the following logs.

> Dec 02, 2016 12:51:44 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor
>   selectAuthScheme INFO: basic authentication scheme selected Dec 02,
>   2016 12:51:44 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
>   processWWWAuthChallenge INFO: No credentials available for BASIC
>   'AXIS'@example.com:443

I encoded the user and password before passing in the url. I am not getting any clue how to fix this. Pleas someone help.

Answer (score 0):

you are using Apache HttpClient, so you should do it better in this way:

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "userpass");
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet("http://domain.com"));
```

Check this great example: [HttpClient Basic Authentication](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication)

Comment: It can be help in my use case But I was looking particularly for hitting like **http://user:password@example.com**

Comment: @sbmc7 in this case use HttpURLConnection